# ChromeDriver sitting on Data:, when launching selenium/cucumber test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have hit a brick wall here; I am completely unable to run any selenium tests on Chrome, as every time I launch it, the chrome browser will open and hang for 600 seconds, with Data:, in the address bar. I have tried every solution under the sun found so far on stack overflow.

- Verified the versions between ChromeDriver and Chrome browser - yes they match.
- Uninstalled/reinstalled chrome several times, and also verified the versions match.

The interesting thing is that running the tests on Microsoft Edge work fine, which leads me to believe there could be an issue with Chrome/Chromedriver not having the correct permissions? The machine the tests are running on is managed by my company. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem - the administrators of the computers I was using had not given access to Chrome's developer tools. After getting access, the problem had gone away. Hope this helps anyone else who encounters this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the configuration of the WebDriver object.

If you use Maven, there is a library which helps configuring the webdrivers. Or if you aren't, then you can download the .jar file and add it to your build path.

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

With this, you don't need to download the driver file itself and set the system property for it's value.

Here is a quick example for creating the ChromeDriver object:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The same thing on Edge:

```
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

Try this at your WebDriver configuration and maybe it can help!

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response - but we're already using WebDriverManager. It's fantastic. We've got the exact setup as on the failing machine on other, working machines with no problems, hence why I've gone to the conclusion of a permissions error.